# How to use Google Maps API to get state (Germany) from zip code?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use the Google Maps API to get the state (Lower Saxony, Bavaria, …) from German zip codes.

I tried this:

```
$get = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $zip . "&sensor=true";
$result = file_get_contents($get);
```

But it returns other matches as well. I would like to limit the matches to Germany (country code: `DE`).

Comment: I think you can add a region to bias the results, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes ~ `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $zip . "&sensor=true&region=de`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *components* parameter as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Example:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=79098&components=country:DE`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [ComponetFiltering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering), so you can filter the results by country.

EX: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:2000|country:AU`